# "Dynamic" cell subtraction in a column with potential blanks

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make a table where a cell in each subsequent row subtracts from the previous one to show the change between the two. The problem is each row isn't always populated so something like A2-A3 then A3-A4, A4-A5, etc. will not work.

How can I skip blank rows in the formula to achieve a result like shown in the attached image (A6 being subtracted from A3 since A4/A5 are blank).

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In b3,

```
=if(a3<>"", abs(a3 - index(a:a, match(1e99, a$1:a2))), "")
```

I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle the subtraction so I made the difference an absolute value.

Comment: So using your code in the crappy sample table I had worked fine, but when translating it into my table something is breaking. I am guessing my lack of knowledge on the Match portion is probably the cause                              =IF(C13<>"", ABS(C13 - INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C$10:C12))), "")

Comment: Got it, I incorrectly assumed the Match A$1:A2 was a cell range. Switching the C$10 to C$1.